# How can we set the javascript variable as jsf parameter

Tags: javascript, jsf

In this code I want use script variable in jsf page

```
<script>
var str;
function demo()
{
  str = 'This is demo';
 } 
</script>

<h:commandButton value="Confirm" action="#{mybean2.getOutcome}" actionListener="#{mybean2.attrListener}">

<f:attribute name="entitle" value="here I want to place script variable "/>
</commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are using Primefaces and its brilliant addon Primefaces Extensions, then you could solve your problem in a following fashion:

**XHTML**

```
<pe:remoteCommand id="myCommand" name="sendPerson" process="@this"  actionListener="#{myBean.myAction}">  
    <pe:methodSignature parameters="java.lang.String, com.yourproject.model.Person" /> 
    <pe:methodParam name="headline"/>   
    <pe:methodParam name="person">  
        <pe:convertJson />  
    </pe:methodParam>  
</pe:remoteCommand>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    var headline = 'This is demo';
    person = {  
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Doe',  
        age: 30,  
        profession: 'Ventriloquist'  
    };  
</script>  

<p:commandButton value="Submit Person" type="button" onclick="sendPerson(headline, JSON.stringify(person))" />
```

Your bean would need two properties `String` ,a `com.yourproject.model.Person` Object that has all the properties that JavaScript object has - 3 `String`s and an `int` and a method that takes those two params:

**Bean**

```
private String headline;
private Person person;

public void myAction(final String headline, final Person person) {
    System.out.println(headline + " " + person);
}

Setters/Getters
```

Here's the link [Primefaces Extensions MethodParam](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/remoteCommand/methodParam.jsf)

Comment: Thanks Kuba, but I am using jsf1.2, I think Primefaces are not supported to my project

Comment: I see, well in this case you'd be better off with a kind of jQuery walk-around. PS. It's always a good thing to post your technology stack alongside your question.